# How do I make a daily action(Android Studio)

Tags: android

I recently started learning about app programing, and I am having a problem.
I want to know how can i make my app do a certain action every time a day is passing.
For example, If i have an int parameter that Equals 10 and today is Sunday.
I need that on Monday the Parameter will be 9,
and on the next day 8, and so on....

Can anyone help me with this?

Answer (score 0):

If you want your app to start every x time, you should use [AlarmManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html) for that and also consider registering for [boot_complete](http://www.learn-android-easily.com/2013/07/bootcompleted-broadcastreceiver-in.html) broadcast.

If you simply need this for calculation, you should use [System.getCurrentTimeMillis](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/System.html) to get the current time and make your decisions.

Comment: Lets say I need that the app will give a notification every day
how do i use AlarmManager to do it?